# Add UILongPressGestureRecognizer to multiple buttons inside a UIScrollView

Tags: uibutton

I have 5-10 diffrent buttons inside a `UIScrollView`.

I want to add a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to all the buttons inside my `UIScrollView`.

```
-(IBAction)CheckIfUserWantsToDoSomething:(id)sender {
    HoldTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.2 target:self selector:@selector(DoAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void)DoAction:(id)sender {
    [HoldTimer invalidate];

    //My Code...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all the `UIScrollView`'s `subviews`, and filter out the `UIButton`'s like so:

```
for (UIButton *button in myScrollView.superview.subviews) {
    if ([button isKindOfClass[UIButton Class]]) {

    }
}
```

Then you can create and add your `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to those buttons.

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *holdRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(DoAction:)];
[holdRecognizer setMinimumPressDuration:2];

[button addGestureRecognizer:holdRecognizer];
```